# How to improve performance of searching and modifying a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, algorithm, dataset

I want to loop through a 2D array, which has a length of around 5 million, for example:

```
//suppose I have two arrays (array1) (array2) (array3)
container =[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,1,9,11,12,14,13], ..so on] //length of array is 5 million

indexOfContainer = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ... 4999999, 5000000 so on] //it stores the index of each element of (container)

items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
```

Basically what I want to do is loop through the container and check if the element of the sub-array of container exists in items. Then I want to delete the index of the sub-array of the container from the index container. I am using brute force for this, which is taking a hell of a lot of time.

Here is my code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j <container[i].length; j++)
        for (let k = 0; k < items.length ; k++)
            if (container[i][j] == items[k])
            {
               indexOfContainer.splice(container.indexOf(i), 1);
            }
    
}
```

This is working but taking around 300 - 1500 milliseconds. I need to use it a thousand times, which increases execution time further.

Is there a way I can reduce execution time drastically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add an example with a smaller data set and the wanted result.

Comment: You're going to probably need to preprocess your data to make it a format that can leverage a better algorithm. What is the actual format of your data (I presume the given example is contrived)? Can it be ordered in such a way that a binary search can be used? Or a hash table for indexing? More information about the use case would be helpful.

Comment: "Multithreading" with [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) _may_ help

Comment: `container.indexOf(i)` is always `-1`?

Comment: Since we don't have adequate information to know for sure, I'll give you some broad tips. Right now you have 3 nested loops, or an O(n * m * k) algorithm. If you wan't to improve the performance, you need to remove one of those products (loops) or multiply it by a coefficient less than 1. Hashtables (objects in javascript) allow for O(1) constant time operations. if you could preprocess an object where the values you're searching for were the keys and the values were where that item is found, that could be a means of removing one of those loops.

Comment: Alternatively, if you could manage to cut the loop short of looking at _every_ index of the array, say make it so you only have to look at half of the array, that would decrease the loop's duration (multiply by a coefficient less than 1... 1/2 in this case). If your data can be sorted then you can look up how to do a `binary search` which would make that coefficient a logarithm making it *much* more efficient. Good luck!

Comment: @Andreas the function in which this loop was called is already an forked process and if i 
devide the loop and initialise more processes from the current process it take too much time.